# React Native - The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 7.0

Tags: ios, react-native, ios-simulator, simulator

I cannot build a React Native app on iOS simulator. I am getting this error over and over. Here is my console output

```
 Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone SE (2nd generation) in debug mode...
    Xcode build done.                                           26,7s
    Failed to build iOS app
    Error output from Xcode build:
    ↳
        ** BUILD FAILED **
    Xcode's output:
    ↳
        note: Using new build system
        note: Building targets in parallel
        note: Planning build
        note: Constructing build description
        warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.4.99. (in target 'AppAuth' from project 'Pods')
        warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.4.99. (in target 'GTMAppAuth' from project 'Pods')
        warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.4.99. (in target 'gRPC-Core' from project 'Pods')
        warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.4.99. (in target 'BoringSSL-GRPC' from project 'Pods')
        warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 5.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.4.99. (in target 'leveldb-library' from project 'Pods')
        warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.4.99. (in target 'gRPC-C++-gRPCCertificates-Cpp' from project 'Pods')
        warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 4.3, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.4.99. (in target 'nanopb' from project 'Pods')
        warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.4.99. (in target 'GTMSessionFetcher' from project 'Pods')
        warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.4.99. (in target 'gRPC-C++' from project 'Pods')
        warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.4.99. (in target 'abseil' from project 'Pods')
    Exited (sigterm)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To get rid of this warning:

```
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.4.99. (in target 'AppAuth' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.4.99. (in target 'GTMAppAuth' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.4.99. (in target 'gRPC-Core' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.4.99. (in target 'BoringSSL-GRPC' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 5.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.4.99. (in target 'leveldb-library' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.4.99. (in target 'gRPC-C++-gRPCCertificates-Cpp' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 4.3, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.4.99. (in target 'nanopb' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.4.99. (in target 'GTMSessionFetcher' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.4.99. (in target 'gRPC-C++' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.4.99. (in target 'abseil' from project 'Pods')
```

Make sure your **Podfile** contains this line

**config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '9.0'**

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
        config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '9.0'
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Removing the set IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET value in the build setting and let it auto config worked for me. In your Podfile, add

```rb
post_install do |installer|
   installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
     target.build_configurations.each do |config|
       config.build_settings.delete 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
     end
   end
end
```